# Laravel Mailable Preview not taking account of the ->theme(...) method call on Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have two different types of theme/css for my emails that are sent from my app. A default one for system emails (reset password etc) and one for consumer emails (emails as a result of actions form users within the app).

In my consumer emails, in the `toMail()` method of the mailable/notification I execute the mailable like so:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->theme($this->theme)
        ->from($this->booking->school->school_email, $this->booking->school->name)
        ->subject($this->getSubject())
        ->attachData($this->booking->payments()->first()->toPdf()->output(), 'Invoice.pdf')
        ->markdown('mail.notifications.bookings.paid_booking', $this->toArray());
}
```

Notice that I call `->theme(...)` on the mailable. This works perfectly fine and the correct theme is set in the template that is received in the mailbox.

When I try to use Laravel's Mailable Preview within a route:

```
Route::get('/mail/resetpass', function () {
    return (new App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification('token'))->toMail(\App\User::find(2));
});

Route::get('/mail/reserved', function () {
    $booking = \App\Domains\Customers\Models\Booking::find(1);
    return (new \App\Domains\Customers\Notifications\ReservedBookingConfirmation($booking))->toMail($booking->customer);
});
```

The "default" theme, as defined in my config files is the one that is used, and my call to `->theme(...)` is ignored.

Is there a solution for this? Changing the config value, isn't a feasible option as I actually want to use this functionality to allow my users to view their emails in the browser. I'm unsure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the `render()` method of the `Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage` class.

**This is fixed in Laravel 8 and so this solution only applies if your project is using laravel 7 or below**

it does not call the theme. I extended the class and have overridden the render method. Adding the call to `->theme(...)` like so.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Mail\Markdown;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage as Original;

class MailMessage extends Original
{
    /**
     * Render the mail notification message into an HTML string.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        if (isset($this->view)) {
            return Container::getInstance()->make('mailer')->render(
                $this->view, $this->data()
            );
        }

        return Container::getInstance()
            ->make(Markdown::class)
            ->theme($this->theme ?? config('mail.markdown.theme')) //add this line here
            ->render($this->markdown, $this->data());
    }
}
```